# Am I missing a badge?

Tags: support, badges

I happened to glance at my progress towards the various badges yesterday and noticed something peculiar. My current progress for [Epic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/42/epic) is marked as 2/50. Epic states that it is for reaching the 200 daily limit 50 times. However, [Mortarboard](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard) is awarded for reaching the 200 daily limit, and I only have one.

Is Mortarboard awarded only once, am I missing a Mortarboard badge, or are Epic and Mortarboard calculated differently? (I don't remember hitting the 200 mark except once...)

*Side Note: Congrats to Samuel for being the only user with Epic.*

Comment: Thanks, it's good evidence that I've lost more rep than anyone else.

Comment: @Samuel Well, you could always slow down and let other people answer from time to time. :)

Comment: I offered that in my campaign. There were no takers, or not enough, obviously :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, Mortarboard is only awarded once.**

This is the case with most non-question/answer badges, with the exception of a few like Socratic.

Epic and Legendary are also awarded only once.

See also [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188731/274942).

Comment: Oh well. I was always looking forward to getting Mortarboard again. Curiously, I did hit the 200 mark twice, but I don't remember what I did late spring of last year to manage that... Ha. Just checked. That was back when I was more active in answering questions.